# Getting "NameError: name 'leader' is not defined". What does this mean?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making a short little test, and I'm planning to have achievements and such. However the code doesn't work

All of this is the achievements and the variables, this message is displayed after reaching this point:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 106, in
> <module> NameError: name 'leader' is not defined

```
if sad == 1:
    if fear == 0 and leader == 1 and known == 1:
        print("Congrats, you are the 'Foolish Leader'1/13")
elif fear == 1 and leader == 1 and known == 0:
    print("Congrats, you are the 'Smart, yet scared Leader'2/13")
elif fear == 0 and leader == 1 and known == 0:
    print("Congrats, you are the 'Smart Leader'3/13")
elif fear == 1 and leader == 0 and known == 1:
    print("Congrats, you are the 'Scared Fool'4/13")
elif sad == 1 and coward == 1:
    print("Congrats, you are the 'Sad Coward'5/13")
elif fear == 1 and coward == 1:
    print("Congrats, you are the 'Scared Coward'6/13")
elif sad == -1:
    if mind_changed == 1:
        print("Congrats, you can't make up your mind.7/13")
elif mind_changed == 0:
    print("Congrats, you can make up your mind.8/13")
elif insane == 1:
    print("Congrats, you are a horrible person and I never want to see you again.9/13")
elif lazy == 1:
    print("Congrats, you are lazy.10/13")
elif suic == True:
    print("I hope that you're ok.11/13")
elif envy == 1:
    print("Congrats, you're a good person.12/13")
elif fear == 1:
    print("Congrats, you're scared easily.13/13")

if suic == True:
    print("I hope you're ok.... Due to you choosing 'C' on the Multiple Choice, I suggest you stop playing.?/13")
```

I was expecting to get achievements and such.

Comment: "'leader' is not defined" < Did you define a variable named leader?

Comment: Pretty straightforward. Your variable `leader` is not defined before you check it in your `if` conditions. Somewhere above the code you've copied and pasted, you've failed to include a line that sets `leader` to something.

Comment: why are you using `int`s instead of `bool` values?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The error you posted `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 106, in <module> NameError: name 'leader' is not defined` tells you that on line 106 your program tries to access the variable 'leader' without it being defined first.

Are you defining this variable before you use it (e.g. `leader = 0`)? Maybe you're defining it in an if-statement which might not always execute?

Comment: ok there is a leader variable its just not included, im only including the area that causes problems

Comment: @PythonToast You need to include all relevant code to reproducing the problem. If your problem is that you think you defined `leader` before this code but your code where you use `leader` tells you it's not defined, then you should probably include the code where you defined it since that's the "area that causes problems."

Comment: yes maybe going to try changing it from numbers to true or false statements